# Hydrogen Spectra

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, hydrogen

I am talking about hydrogen spectral lines such as Lyman, Balmer etc. In order to make those spectral lines series more than one electron are needed to jump from higher orbits to lower orbit. But there is only one electron in an hydrogen atom. 
How does hydrogen spectrum happen then?

Comment: *"In order to make those spectral lines series more than one electron are needed to jump from higher orbits to lower orbit."* [citation needed]

Comment: Actually, you wouldn't see the lines with only one hydrogen, you need millions and millions of hydrogens to see the lines. This is where all those electrons come from.

Comment: But pointedly one electron per atom. If you have two (or more) you get a different spectrum (more like Helium's).

Answer (score 3):

If you had a *single* hydrogen atom, and you watched for a *single* transition, then yes, you would only see emission at a single frequency. There would be one line in your spectrograph so to speak.

But rarely do you have just one atom. And quite often an atom undergoes multiple transitions while you are watching it. When looking at a large ensemble, whether it be a lamp or a star, you might have some fraction of the electrons decaying $n = 2 \to 1$, others going $n = 4 \to 2$, and still others rapidly transitioning $n = 4 \to 3 \to 2$ while you gather data. The relative numbers of such occurrences translates into line strengths, from which you can learn statistical information about the ensemble as a whole.